# Remove characters in string before specific symbol(including it)

Tags: r, regex, gsub

at the beginning, yes - simillar questions are present here, however the solution doesn't work as it should - at least for me.

I'd like to remove all characters, letters and numbers with any combination before first semicolon, and also remove it too.

So we have some strings:

```
x <- "1;ABC;GEF2"
y <- "X;EER;3DR"
```

Let's do so `gsub()` with `.` and `*` which means any symbol with occurance 0 or more:

```
gsub(".*;", "", x)
gsub(".*;", "", y)
```

And as a result i get:

```
[1] "GEF2"
[1] "3DR"
```

But I'd like to have:

```
[1] "ABC;GEF2"
[1] "EER;3DR"
```

Why did it 'catch' second occurence of semicolon instead of first?

Comment: `sub("^.*?;", "", x)`, 1. sub 2. use non-greedy

Comment: Try with `sub` i.e. `sub("^[^;]*;", "", x)`

Comment: Each solution works great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
gsub("[^;]*;(.*)", "\\1", x)
# [1] "ABC;GEF2"
```